# missing start script in NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, heroku, npm

First, sorry for my bad english.
I'm trying to deploy an app to Heroku using the command `heroku local web` in terminal,  but I'm getting `ERR! missing script: start`, even though I have the script in my json file. And if I try to run `npm start` in terminal the same error appears. I searched for similar problems in Stack Overflow but I couldn't solve.
My .json is:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    .
    .
    My dependencies here
    .
    .
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: nko test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

PS.: When I run `npm install` in terminal, the json file just erases the script and everything I wrote, for example I added `"config" : { "port" : "3000" }`, but after running `npm install` it just disappeared.

Comment: How did you created your package.json file? Did you do 'npm init' ? What operating system?

Comment: Yes, I used npm init. I'm using Linux Fedora 27

Answer (score -1):

I think you confused `yarn` and `npm`

If you want to use `yarn` and if you `package.json` contain a key like `start` you can call `yarn start`

But, if you want to work with `npm` you need to use `npm run start` the `run` it's important because `npm` can't understand.

Comment: I think I don't need to use because it's a default script, but even if I use  'npm run start' the error don't disappear.